# Get .lib address

Tags: winapi, assembly, linker, import

I'm currently learning how linking/compiling works and just came to the topic about the IMPORTS of a .exe file. I see that the (Microsoft) Linker might need a .lib file from the Win32 SDK to resolve external functions. For example if you would like to use the `MessageBoxA` from the `user32.dll` you actually need the `_MessageBoxA@16` address from the user32.lib to resolve it. So how is it possible for the user/programmer to find out which "Prefix" I need to resolve it?! (Like other User32/Kernel32 functions...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_MessageBoxA@16 is the symbol that the compiler generated from the declaration in the WinUser.h #include file.  It is a *decorated* name, the underscore and @ postfix are used for functions that are declared __stdcall.  Name decoration helps catch declaration mistakes at link time.  But is not actually used for winapi functions, they have undecorated names.  Mostly to help make it easy to use GetProcAddress().

User32.lib is *not* a normal library, it is an **import library**.  It doesn't contain the code for MessageBoxA, it merely contains a list of all the functions that are exported by user32.dll.  And it contains the mapping from the compiler generated name, _MessageBoxA@16 to the name it is actually exported from user32.dll, MessageBoxA.  Microsoft used a "module definition file", [a .def file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28d6s79h%28v=VS.80%29.aspx), to create this mapping when they built user32.dll

The linker uses user32.lib to resolve the symbol.  It knows from the import library how to create the import table entry in the EXE, using the proper name of the exported function.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But that still doesn't explain how you can find out which name to use for functions in user32.lib or kernel32.lib, etc. It may be defined in WinUser.h but how can me as the programmer find the name without the WinUser.h?! Is there a documentary somewhere?

Comment: Well, it does, I used the word "mapping" several times in my answer.  Follow the link I gave for .def files to see how these mappings are created.

Comment: I think you might misunderstood my question. Say I want to use the function VirtualAlloc, which is declared in the the .obj file as a  'VirtualAlloc' external, would probably cause an error or no import at all. I actually have to use _VirtualAlloc@16 or I could even use _VirtualAlloc@900 or _VirtualAlloc@12345. So how do I know which is the right name?

Comment: You cannont use _VirtualAlloc@900, because that function dont exist. Hans answer is exact.

Comment: Why can't you use _VirtualAlloc@900? So I can use _VirtualAlloc@12345? I'm sorry but this question is not answered yet. Though I appreciate the additional info.

Comment: Because 16 is number of bytes of arguments.

Comment: Read the first line in my answer again.  The symbol is **not** arbitrary, the compiler generates it from the declaration.